# after ruby upgrade: Failed to build gem native extension. (EC2 Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04, idn

I tried to switch my ruby version from `1.8` (default) to `1.9.3` (latest on Pangolin) as per http://lenni.info/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/. I'm doing this using `apt`.

The other solutions to related questions on SO involve `apt-get install ruby1.9.3-dev` but I definitely have it.

```
$ sudo gem install idn
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing idn:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lidn... yes
checking for idna.h... yes
checking for punycode.h... yes
checking for stringprep.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling idn.c
compiling idna.c
idna.c: In function ‘toASCII’:
idna.c:88:37: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
idna.c: In function ‘toUnicode’:
idna.c:128:41: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
make: *** [idna.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/idn-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/idn-0.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have also checked that I have `gcc` installed and it's again installed from `apt`.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing some headers. Either when compiling Ruby or IDN's. Perhaps `zlib1g-dev`.

Comment: @harm thanks! let me try it. ... `zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.` hmm.

Comment: That sounds like the gem just isn't compatible with ruby 1.9 (which changed how you access string data from a c extension)

Answer (score 1):

I may give up on this one. I was able to install the `punycode4r` gem and that works for what I'm trying to do.